# Google Apps Script onEdit(e) does not trigger on source of cut and paste

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an Apps Script that writes or removes values or formats to the right of an edited cell or range. Here is a *simplified* sample of the working code:

```
function onEdit(e) { myFunction(e) };

function myFunction(e) {
  for (let c=1; c <= e.range.getNumColumns(); c++) {
    for (let r=1; r <= e.range.getNumRows(); r++) {
      let cell = e.range.getCell(r, c);
      if ( cell.getValue() ) {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn()+1).setValue("OK");
        // Do other things...
      } else {
        e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell.getRow(), cell.getColumn()+1).clearContent();
        // Do other things...
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The code triggers for all sorts of new entries, edits, deletes, etc... except for one: **cut and paste**.

If you put the code above in your Apps Script, and type anything on any cell, the cell on its right will soon have the value `OK`. Delete what you typed, and the OK next to it will soon be deleted. This works on ranges as well.

However, try this: Type a value, then cut and paste it somewhere. An `OK` should appear next to where you pasted it, but the `OK` next to the removed value still remains. It did not trigger on the source of the cut.

Any way to provide a solution for this, i.e. running the code in the cut range as well? (If the range was simply deleted, it works.)

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet with your data so that I can understand your concern better. Remove sensitive information.

Comment: - [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: Try using an installable trigger.  simple triggers cannot perform tasks that require permission.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior and limitations of the `OnEdit` trigger.

It is designed to run when a user makes manual edits to a cell in a spreadsheet and it has limited access to clipboard meaning it can only read the value of the modified cell or range.

To solve your concern, I suggest you can use manual trigger
via `custom menu`, separating the `cut` and `paste` operations like in this SO: [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/onedit-only-updates-top-row-after-pasting-editing-multiple-rows)

Comment: Hi Twilight! Thank you for answering. I also checked the link you shared. In fact I realized that the code above answers his question. ;-) I think there was a misunderstanding of my question. I updated it and hopefully that clarifies it. Thank you for the time.